# how to compile scss with keyframes

Tags: webpack, sass, node-modules, css-loader, sass-loader

I have error after `npm run dev` if I add following code in my `_mobmenu.scss` partial
When this part of code is commented I have no errors.

```
@keyframes openbt {
  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
  to   { :before { content: '\e804'; } }
}

@keyframes closebt {
  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
  to   { :before { content: '\e804'; } }
}

.openbt:before {
  animation: openbt 2s;
  content: '\e804';
}

.closebt:before {
  animation: closebt 2s;
  content: '\f0c9';
}
```

I cannot understand which number is expected here.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                        12:32:49

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
        ^
      Expected number.
   ╷
14 │   from { :before{ content: '\f0c9'; } }
   │          ^
   ╵
  resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss 14:10  @import
  stdin 33:9                                   root stylesheet
      in C:\laragon\www\lara7\resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss (line 14, column 10)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:89:7
    at Function.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:87584:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:77359:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24165:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23557:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3253:17)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:13333:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3276:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23578:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23570:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24165:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23557:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3253:17)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:15991:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3276:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23578:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23570:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
        ^
      Expected number.
   ╷
14 │   from { :before{ content: '\f0c9'; } }
   │          ^
   ╵
  resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss 14:10  @import
  stdin 33:9                                   root stylesheet
      in C:\laragon\www\lara7\resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss (line 14, column 10)

 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-256

       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
  /js/app.js  7.11 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
\css\app.css   262 KiB           [emitted]
  \js\app.js  7.11 MiB           [emitted]

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
        ^
      Expected number.
   ╷
14 │   from { :before{ content: '\f0c9'; } }
   │          ^
   ╵
  resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss 14:10  @import
  stdin 33:9                                   root stylesheet
      in C:\laragon\www\lara7\resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss (line 14, column 10)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:89:7
    at Function.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:87584:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:77359:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24165:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23557:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3253:17)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:13333:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3276:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23578:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23570:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)
    at _Future._completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24165:9)
    at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23557:12)
    at Object._asyncRethrow (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3253:17)
    at C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:15991:20
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3276:15)
    at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23578:12)
    at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:23570:25)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25587:18)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:25591:19)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24041:19)
    at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:24337:40)
    at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (C:\laragon\www\lara7\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js:3497:88)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

  from { :before { content: '\f0c9'; } }
        ^
      Expected number.
   ╷
14 │   from { :before{ content: '\f0c9'; } }
   │          ^
   ╵
  resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss 14:10  @import
  stdin 33:9                                   root stylesheet
      in C:\laragon\www\lara7\resources\sass\includes\_mobmenu.scss (line 14, column 10)
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-256
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anastasia\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-17T09_32_51_476Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anastasia\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-17T09_32_51_521Z-debug.log
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
        "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.4",
        "laravel-mix-postcss-config": "^1.0.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
        "vue-directive-long-press": "^1.1.0",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
        "webpack": "^4.43.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@rdebeasi/flexmenu": "^1.6.2",
        "clean-css-cli": "^4.3.0",
        "cleave.js": "^1.5.3",
        "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
        "ekko-lightbox": "^5.3.0",
        "laravel-mix-clean-css": "^1.3.1",
        "laravel-mix-imagemin": "^1.0.3",
        "lg-autoplay": "^1.0.4",
        "lg-fullscreen": "^1.1.0",
        "lg-hash": "^1.0.4",
        "lg-pager": "^1.0.2",
        "lg-share": "^1.1.0",
        "lg-thumbnail": "^1.1.0",
        "lg-video": "^1.2.2",
        "lg-zoom": "^1.1.0",
        "lightgallery": "^1.6.12",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "sass-flex-mixin": "^1.0.3",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
        "vue-toasted": "^1.1.27",
        "vuex": "^3.4.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is only with the syntax here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is your scss syntax, no need to mention before after in keyframes, as you already applied the animation on same.

Make it correct like this.

```
@keyframes openbt {
    from {
        content: '\f0c9';
    }
    to {
        content: '\e804';
    }
}

@keyframes closebt {
    from {
        content: '\f0c9';
    }
    to {
        content: '\e804';
    }
}

.openbt{
    &:before {
        animation: openbt 2s;
        content: '\e804';
    }
}

.closebt{
    &:before {
        animation: closebt 2s;
        content: '\f0c9';
    }
}
```

Chek this running Example

```css
@-webkit-keyframes changeLetter {
  0% {
    content: "1";
  }
  100% {
    content: "2";
  }
}
@keyframes changeLetter {
  0% {
    content: "1";
  }
  100% {
    content: "2";
  }
}
.element {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.element:after {
  -webkit-animation: changeLetter 3s linear infinite alternate;
          animation: changeLetter 3s linear infinite alternate;
  display: block;
  content: "A";
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

the above running example is in CSS, here is the SCSS for the same, doesn't matter its CSS or SCSS, logic will remain same.

```
@keyframes changeLetter {
0% {
    content: "1";
 }
 100% {
   content: "2";
 }
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  &:after {
    animation: changeLetter 3s linear infinite alternate;
    display: block;
    content: "A";
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
```